# Is there a concept of partial layouts that can be changed during runtime without sliding?

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to find out what technique I have to use with my intended approach.

I have a layout that should consist of 3 parts: a top and right part that stay the same and a left part that can change in runtime. When the user decides to change this left part, it should display another layout at that location.

So far I've found these approaches:

- **ViewFlipper**
  Not really what I'm looking for since it's used by sliding your finger to the side instead of pressing a button
- **ViewPager**
  Seems to be pretty much the same as the ViewFlipper.
- **ViewStub**
  Can only be used once so not a viable option (I want the user to be able to change back and forth).

Sadly, none of them do the job (unless I have misinterpreted something). Is it even possible to do what I want?

Comment: How many possible different `layout`s are you going to have and how different are they from each other? You could simply have them in your xml in the same position and change the `visibility`. Or use `fragments`

Comment: From the looks of it that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'll look into fragments, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something not too complex, you could go with [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html).

For something more advanced [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) are the [solution](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace).

**Note:** You could call `setDisplayedChild()` on a `ViewFlipper` to programmatically switch between views.

You could also call `setCurrentItem()` on a `ViewPager` (which by the way can use Fragments).